# why VGA laptop detects monitor with Dual-Link DVI-D, but monitor does not display?

Tags: vga, dvi

I have a laptop with VGA video output, and I bought a simple adapter from VGA to DVI-D, and I am trying to connect a big monitor using Dual-Link DVI-D to the laptop.

When I do this, the laptop Windows Display GUI Detects the Big Monitor, identifies it correctly and identifies the maximum resolution to it.  I can dual-display to both of them, and the cursor moves off of the small laptop screen and into the Big Monitor.

Except, nothing is actually displayed on the Big Monitor, it is black.  When I disconnect the cable, it cycles RGB default screens, so I know the power is on to it.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

So, well. The adapter you bought is meant to “extract” the VGA signal from a DVI-A connector. DVI-A is a true analog (hence “A”) VGA signal. That means it doesn’t convert anything but the connector type. So, when you employ it in reverse, it converts to DVI-A. Most displays do not support DVI-A. If they employ proper (DVI-D) connectors, a DVI-A plug will not fit.

To convert VGA to DVI-D (“D” as in digital, which is what your monitor wants), you need an active converter. Something like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DRG1TLS). Converting to HDMI is fine, because it’s fully compatible with DVI at these resolutions.